# regular expression for date and time diffrent ways

Tags: regex

I am learning regular expression so I did some example. For example I want to validate date `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss` or `dd-mm-yyy hh:mm:ss`

I did like this on https://regex101.com:

`([0-9]{2}+[-\/]+[0-9]{2}+[-\/]+[0-9]{4})\s([0-9]{2}+:+[0-9]{2}+:+[0-9]{2})`

`(\d{2}+[-\/]+\d{2}+[-\/]+\d{4})\s(\d{2}+:+\d{2}+:+\d{2})`

Is there any other way to do it so regex can be short? Or it is perfect, I am sure it is not 100% perfect.
i want to add range for example month should not be greater than 12 , in time it should not be grater that 60.

Comment: Is `/\d{2}([\/-])\d{2}\1\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/` enough?

Comment: Why is this tagged regex-lookarounds?

Comment: what if i want to add range, for example month should not greater than 12 .

Comment: I'd recommend doing the date/time validation elsewhere: It can get a bit nasty to do it all with regex, especially when you get to leap years and leap seconds, not to mention DST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a date validator that I created for this, I think it could be fixed a little but it is working

```js
test()

function dateChecker(re, dOrder, s) {
  var validity = {
    pass: false,
    testString: s
  }
  s.replace(re, function(full, date, seperator, time) {
    var y, m, d, h, min, s, p;
    date = date.split(seperator).map(Number);
    date[1] --;
    time = time ? time.split(':').map(Number) : [0, 0, 0];
    p = new Date(
      y = date[dOrder.y],
      m = date[dOrder.m],
      d = date[dOrder.d],
      h = time[0],
      min = time[1],
      s = time[2]);
    if (p.getDate() === d && 
        p.getMonth() === m && 
        p.getFullYear() === y && 
        p.getHours() === h && 
        p.getMinutes() === min && 
        p.getSeconds() === s)
      validity.pass = true;
    else
      validity.failReason = [p, "doesn't match", date, time].join(' ')
  });
  return validity
}

function dValidator(s) {
  return dateChecker(/^((?:\d\d([-\/])){2}\d{4})(?:\s+((?:\d\d:){2}\d\d))?$/, {
    d: 0,
    m: 1,
    y: 2
  }, s)
}

function test() {
  var failedTests = [],
    failData = ["33/09/2064", "31/2/1980"],
    sucessData = ["14-03-1904 04:35:17", "29/2/1980"];
  failData.map(dValidator).map(function(a, i) {
    return a.pass ? failedTests.push([a, i, 'expected to fail but it incorrectly passed']) : console.log('test passed ok', a, i)
  })
  sucessData.map(dValidator).map(function(a, i) {
    return a.pass ? console.log('test passed ok', a, i) : failedTests.push([a, i, 'expected to pass but it has incorrectly failed'])
  })
  if (failedTests.length) {
    console.log(failedTests);
    return 'fail'
  }
  return 'pass'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using too much +, and you could repeat some groups :

```
(\d{2}[-\/]){2}\d{4}\s\d{2}(:\d{2}){2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found  for date  m/d/yy or m/d/yyyy or mm/dd/yy or mm/dd/yy

```
^((0?[13578]|10|12)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[01]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1}))|(0?[2469]|11)(-|\/)(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|([12])([0-9]?)|(3[0]?))(-|\/)((19)([2-9])(\d{1})|(20)([01])(\d{1})|([8901])(\d{1})))$
```